# FullCalendar v2 error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'month' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I'm using the select callback when adding events. The following code worked in v1 but I'm getting the Uncaught TypeError in v2. When I remove the ajax code there is no error but of course I need to add the new event to the database.

```
select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view) {
  var title = 'Available';
  var eventData;
  eventData = {
    title: title,
    start: start
  };
  $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'add-event.php',
    data: eventData,
    success : function(data){
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
        id: data.id,
        title: data.title,
        start: data.start,
        start: data.end
      }, true);
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
    },
    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    }
  });


},
```

Answer (score 10):

Try send startDate and endDate in a format use  `format()` for it.

```
select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view) {
  var title = 'Available';
  var eventData;
  eventData = {
    title: title,
    start: start
  };
  $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'add-event.php',
    data: eventData,
    success : function(data){
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
        id: data.id,
        title: data.title,
        start: data.start.format(),
        end: data.end.format()
      }, true);
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
    },
    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    }
  });


},
```

You can refer to [Momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Please check the event data . Source attribute of your event must be null or not populated. SO before calling

$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', event);

You have to be make sure that required attribute of your fullcalendar event must be populated. Here is the link for required and optional fieldfor event object.

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/

Answer (score 0):

The "calendar" script used in both version is different.

If You observe, the call made to your php file in V1 is:

```
get-events?start=1362076200000&end=1364754600000&_=1403859868502
```

and the call made by V2:

```
get-events.php?start=2014-06-01&end=2014-07-13&_=1403859868502
```

Hope this will help You somewhat.

Comment: True, but if you alert or console.log the start time when using select, it is in javascript timestamp format similar to 1362076200000. The problem I'm having though is the error occurs when I use $.ajax. Take that part out and no error. Why?

Comment: I can't say anything on that because I have't used that method. Try using "$.post" instead. See if it might help.

Comment: please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594685/calling-jquery-ajax-or-jquery-post-from-inside-of-one-of-the-event-callbacks-res?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this and noticed that v2 seems to set some extra _start and _end parameters in the event object. I found that I needed to do: start = _start.format() in order to prevent moment from trying to serialise this. I'm not sure this is the optimal solution, but perhaps it'll help you.