# Calling JQuery.ajax or JQuery.post from inside of one of the event callbacks results in a Type Error from Moment.min.js

Tags: ajax, callback, fullcalendar, typeerror, momentjs

I am working on a schedule using FullCalendar and i have hit a bit of a snag. I am trying to use the event callback functions to create a new event, and send the new event's information to my php script which then stores the information to the server. But whenever i try to call $.ajax or $.post from within one of the callbacks (and i have tried if from with in a few of them) i get this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'month' of undefined moment.js:684
extend.monthsShort moment.js:684
e jquery.min.js:4
Bc jquery.min.js:4
Bc jquery.min.js:4
Bc jquery.min.js:4
n.param jquery.min.js:4
n.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:4
$.fullCalendar.select advisorSchedule.js:141
Q fullcalendar.min.js:6
s fullcalendar.min.js:7
a fullcalendar.min.js:7
(anonymous function) fullcalendar.min.js:6
d jquery.min.js:3
n.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:3
r.handle
```

But because i was using Moment.min.js it was kinda hard to read where the problem was coming from, so i replaces Moment.min.js with Moment.js, and when the error popped up again i was able to read where the problem was:

```
months : function (m) {
   return this._months[m.month()];
},
```

From what i gathered, m is undefined by the time this function is executed.
Here is the code i used to post the new event data to the php script:

```
select:function(start, end, jsEvent, view){
        CURRENT_SELECTION_START = start;
        CURRENT_SELECTION_END   = end;

        console.log(CURRENT_SELECTION_START + '-' + CURRENT_SELECTION_END);

        $.ajax({

            url:'../AJAX/save_event.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                Start_Time: start,
                Event_Title: prompt('Title'),
                End_Time: end
            },

        });
    },
```

Answer (score 16):

I assume start is a moment-object.

I had the same problem and it seems: you can't send the moment-object, so you need to get the value as an integer or something else.

Try `start.calendar()` or `start.format("YYYY-MM-DD");` (or something similar) instead of `start`.

worked for me, hopefully for you too ;)

Patrick

Answer (score 7):

I just had this exact same problem (it's how I came across this post).

To send the whole object you need to stringify it.

```
var now = moment();

$.ajax({
      url: 'http://example.com',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: JSON.stringify(now),
      type: 'POST'
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't send `start` and `end` directly as the parameters to the AJAX request.

```
var startDate = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    endDate = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    params = {'from':startDate, 'to':endDate};
$.ajax({
      url: 'http://example.com',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: params,
      type: 'POST'
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log('Successful! ', data);
    });
```