# jQuery Post in FullCalendar DayClick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, jquery-post

I am running a FullCalendar, and I would like to retrieve some data via a jQuery post when a day is clicked. This is the code:

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
                truckid=jQuery(this).parents(".calendar").attr("data-truck-id");
                alert(truckid);
                jQuery.post( "test.php", { TruckId: truckid, dateUsed: date })
                    .done(function( data ) {
                        alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
                    });
                alert('everything OK');
            },
```

When I include the jQuery post, the script fires the "alert(truckid)" part, and then stops with the following error: 
TypeError: a is undefined (points to moment.min.js a js file of FullCalendar).

If I remove the jQuery post, the code runs correctly, alerting out the last alert too.

What could be the problem? Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Your payload is not properly quoted. This may the cause of your TypeError. Payload should be like `{ 'TruckId': truckid, 'dateUsed': date }`

Comment: No, I don't think so... I am using it like this several other places and it works just fine. Edit: Just to be on the safe side, tried your suggestion, and still the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. The problem is with the date variable, which is a moment object, thus can't be sent this way. Here is a solution to this problem, thanks to PatBau:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24729448/2691879