# moment.js:423 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_calendar' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, fullcalendar, momentjs

I am using fullcalendar, and what I want to make is when user click the event, then ask if user want to extend the class time. If user canceled the course(which is in my DB) before, then user can extend the class time for 15minutes. So, if user can extend the class, then send the information to mysqlDB by using ajax and php. However, the problem is all the information, which is endDate, startDate, and canceledCourseDate, and end(endDate before extend), is correctly sended to ajax, but I got error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_calendar' of undefined

Thus, I searched some information, and I added .format("YYYY-MM_DD HH:mm"), but still have problem.

Here is js code

```
            var canceledList = <?php echo $json_array4; ?>; //not newlyBooked canceled Date List
            var canceledListNum = canceledList.length;
            var extensionList = <?php echo $json_array10; ?>;
            var extendedListNum = extensionList.length;
            var canceledDate = '';
            var extensionStatus = 'going';
            if(extendedListNum > 0)
            {
                canceledDate = extensionList[0]['canceledCourseDate']; //get canceledDate that is alreay in extension
            }
            else if(canceledListNum > 0)
            {
                canceledDate = canceledList[0]['canceledCourseDate']; //if there is no course that is in extension, then get new canceledDate that isn't done yet.
                extensionStatus = 'new';
            }




            var id = calEvent.id;
            var teacher = calEvent.resourceId;



            var extendedDate = moment(calEvent.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"));
            var end = moment(calEvent.end.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"));
            var endDate = moment(end).add(15, 'minutes');

            console.log(start);
            console.log(extendedDate);
            console.log(end);
            console.log(endDate);
            console.log(canceledDate);


            var limit = 2;
            var userDuration = '<?php echo $userDuration; ?>';

            if(userDuration == '60')
            {
                limit = 4;
            }


            if(id == '<?php echo $userID; ?>')
            {


            }
            else // extend lesson 
            {   
                    if(new Date(start) < new Date(today))
                    {
                        alert("cannot extend the class");

                    }
                    else{
                        if(canceledDate == '')
                        {
                            alert("cannot extend the class");
                        }else
                        {
                            $.ajax({
                               url:"extend.php",
                               type:"POST",
                               data:{userName: '<?php echo $name; ?>' , canceledCourseDate: canceledDate, extendedDate: extendedDate , endDate: endDate ,courseTeacher : teacher, userBranch:'<?php echo $userBranch; ?>', userID: '<?php echo $userID; ?>', duration : '<?php echo $userDuration; ?>', originalEnd : end, extensionStatus: extensionStatus},
                               success:function(response)
                               {
                                    console.log(response);
                                    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                                    alert("Successfully extended.");
                                    location.reload();
                               }
                              });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Then here is the image of console,

[image: console response]

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594685/calling-jquery-ajax-or-jquery-post-from-inside-of-one-of-the-event-callbacks-res/24729448#24729448

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var end = moment(calEvent.end.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"));
```

this is not working. However,

```
var endDateForAdd = moment(endDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
```

this is working.